# SQL Random sample table with duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming I have the following table:

```
       unitid  |  transtatus |   currency
    ---------------------------------------
    1024393230 | not_started |  GBp - Pence
    1024397398 | in_progress |  GBp - Pence
    1024397398 | not_started |  USd - Cent
    1024397408 | not_started |  GBp - Pence
    1024397408 | not_started |  EUR
    1024401371 | not_started |  GBp - Pence
    1024403375 | in_progress |  GBp - Pence
```

I want to select random rows for QC I can do it by

```
select top 3  
tbble.unitid,tbble.transtatus, tbble.currency
 from tbble
order by newid()
```

However since some rows share the same unitid (and if this is the case) I want to pull all the rows associated with this unitid

So the query would return: (in case random rows only has one row for this unitid)

```
      unitid   | transtatus  |  currency
    ---------------------------------------
    1024393230 | not_started | GBp - Pence
    1024401371 | not_started | GBp - Pence
    1024403375 | in_progress | GBp - Pence
```

or : (in case of two rows associated with this unitid)

```
    1024397398 | in_progress | GBp - Pence
    1024397398 | not_started | USd - Cent
    1024401371 | not_started | GBp - Pence
    1024403375 | in_progress | GBp - Pence
```

Not really sure how can I achieve this. Maybe counting the number of unitid appearances first and then if count is over 1 then adding these to initial random sample?

Comment: which dbms are you using

Comment: i am using ms sql

Comment: Look at all these responses... does nobody used capitalized keywords anymore? It's like trying to read a book printed without paragraphs.

Comment: @jdl134679 why didn't they make sql CASE sensitive, in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you want, which is three random unit ids and all their rows:

```
select t.*
from tbble t join
     (select top 3 t.unitid
      from (select distinct t.unitid from tbble t) t
      order by newid()
     ) tt
     on t.unitid = tt.unitid
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks a lot. When would I be able to get it myself..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a subquery to work in two steps : first you select some random `unitid` with the subquery, then for each of them, you select the whole rows in your table with the same `unitid`. It should look like this :

```
select tbble.unitid, tbble.transtatus, tbble.currency
from tbble
where tbble.unitid in (select top 3  
tbble.unitid as randomunitid
 from tbble
order by newid())
```

Comment: Sometimes it would return two duplicate rows for unitid that appears once

Answer (score 1):

You should use `WITH TIES` clause to get matching rows

```
select top 3   WITH TIES *
tbble.unitid,tbble.transtatus, tbble.currency
 from tbble
order by newid()
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, would still not go over number 3 in total in case there are 2 rows with same unitid